# What is the white powder that I have extracted from cinnamon?

Tags: organic-chemistry

In Advanced higher chemistry, I am extracting cinnamaldehyde using this procedure- https://www.flinnsci.ca/api/library/Download/ba6ab218508047ea843bb0d9e580be16
. After evaporating the hexane, instead of the cinnamaldehyde (a liquid), a solid white power is formed. We have no clue what it is and think it may be either something that is naturally extracted from the cinnamon bark or something that was added during 'production' (got it from Tesco's).

Comment: I guess the aldehyde may oxidized to solid acid, similarly as liquid  benzaldehyde easily oxidizes to solid benzoic acid.

Answer (score 2):

"6 grams of cinnamon can contain from to 42 to 189 mg cinnamaldehyde." http://herbpedia.wikidot.com/cinnamaldehyde  That's not very much.

"Cinnamon consists of a variety of resinous compounds, including cinnamaldehyde, cinnamate, cinnamic acid, and numerous essential oils." https://www.hindawi.com/journals/ecam/2014/642942/

The extraction method starts with 10 grams of cinnamon and salt is used to salt out the cinnamaldehyde from the steam distillate. Could the solid be salt carried over from the separation funnel? If the solid you obtained is more than about 400 mg, it might well be contaminated with NaCl. You could add a milliliter or two of H2O to see if you get a (saturated) salt solution plus the cinnamaldehyde oil on top. If the cinnamon you started with was very old or had very little cinnamaldehyde to begin with, the amount of oil you obtain might well be overshadowed by a little NaCl contamination.